# Retrieve from Firebase not working with auto generated id react native

Tags: firebase, react-native

Hi I'm retrieving data from firebase with this function in react native and it works fine when the node title is 1 or any other number. But when I use push and firebase will automatically generate an id like Kth6q9p8njLyfwbuyL5 and that's when I can't retrieve in react native. does anyone know why? thanks for help

```
let shiftPath = "/shifts/mobile";

firebase.database().ref(shiftpath).on('value', (snapshot) => {

        this.setState({
          mobile : snapshot.val(),
            });
          });



    }
```

[image: it works with 2 and not with Kth6q9p8njLyfwbuyL5]

Comment: Can you add a `console.log(snapshot.val()` and share the result, please?

Answer (score 0):

They both the same but first one has UUID

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your issue. As the result you posted both objects are being retrieved. The case is that one contains keys and values and the other only keys. Can you clarify exactly what are your trying to achieve? Do you want to add a new item without auto generating the ID?

Comment: I want to be able to retrieve posts with generated ID, but It doesn't work with the above function. it only works with numbered objects like "1" I don't know why.

Comment: This print you posted is the result of your `console.log(snapshot.val()`? If so, notice that the ID object is being listed, thus we can assume it's being retrieved. If you add this code after your setState `console.log('end: ', this.state.mobile['firebaseid'].end)` you should see a response as `'end: '`. This is because your property is empty in your firebase schema. If you want to pass through all your records, you can convert your object to an array using something like `Object.entries(snapshot.val())` and use a `.forEach()` to get each item. Hope it helps.

Comment: Im assiginging the data received from firebase into array then I go trough  it liek this              `  <View>
            {
              this.state.mobile.map((items, i) => {
                return (
                  <Card key={i}
                    title=  {items.position}>
                    <Text> {items.num} </Text>

                    <Button
                        title='Accept...' />
                </Card>);


                
              })
            }

          </View> `

Comment: when I add object with generated id it comes back  this.state.mobile.map  is not a function is undefined

Comment: Probably your this.state.mobile is an object or undefined, that's why you can't map it. Try to console.log it before using map. Also, provide the code you are using to convert it to an array. Have you tried the code I mentioned?

Comment: I can map it  when I have a number as node but not when I have a generated ID. I tried your code but it gives me some firebase warning :   
FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback.